# How to update ionic framework applications?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have app build with `@ionic/angular@5.0`, which used `@angular@8`.
I want to update to current version of ionic (and angular).
How should I do it and in what order (ionic docs say nothing :/ )

1. `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli`
2. `npm i -s @ionic/angular`

Comment: Ideally its best to make a new project and copy the folders :)

Comment: But who wants to do it :)

Comment: No need to make a new project. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Added more notes to the docs issue you opened. this would make for a good dedicated page. In the mean time, in your case, you're already on the latest Ionic (v5 as of august 2020), so this is more about Angular. Follow their [update guide](https://update.angular.io/) - it's very helpful and tells you exactly what commands to run.

Generally, updating Ionic varies by framework, but for Angular:

`npm i @ionic/angular@latest`

and do the same for other @ionic/angular packages